# rsyncd.conf exclude from configuration not working

Tags: rsync

I'm trying to use a text file to contain the excluded files for the rsyncd daemon. I followed the rsyncd.con manual and put:

```
exclude from = /etc/rsync-exclude.txt
```

But it seems not working. What could be the possible cause.

I googled a lot for this problem, but nothing useful turned out.

UPDATE: here is what's in rsync-exclude.txt

```
.git (I also tried putting it as /.git but that didn't work either)
uploads
assets
config.inc.php
```

Here is the global configurations in rsyncd.conf :

```
uid = www
gid = www
max connections = 600
use chroot = no
transfer logging = yes
log file = /var/log/rsyncd.log
log format = %t %a %m %f %b
log file = /var/log/rsyncd.log
pid file=/var/run/rsyncd.pid
lock file=/var/run/rsyncd.lock
#motd file = /etc/rsyncd/rsyncd.motd

read only = no
list = no
ignore errors = yes
```

Comment: On the topic of the question, can you post what files you're trying to exclude, and what config you've put in that file to do it?

Comment: Does it work when specifying a `--exclude-from` from the command line as an argument?

Comment: `rsyncd.conf(5)` says that to exclude entire directories you need to use `/uploads/***`. Also try prefixing the lines with `- ` to make the exclude explicit.